# Bootstrap class row-fluid in react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I want to achieve results of `row-fluid` bootstrap class by using [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) but didn't get a standard way in the library. Something like [fluid prop for Grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#grid-props-grid) component but this is not supported for `Row` component.

I tried exploring the documentation at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/ but didn't get any major help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My main intention was to avoid negative margins of `row` class so using prop `noGutters` as `true` somehow resolved my issue.

```
<Row noGutters={true}>
  ...
</Row>
```

As per [documentation of .no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters):

> The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be
>   removed with .no-gutters. This removes the negative margins from .row
>   and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns.

Another option is to use `Container` component with `fluid` prop as `true` if this fulfil your requirement like:

```
<Container fluid={true}>
  ...
</Container>
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it indeed solved your problem

Comment: It's more like a workaround to deal with the problem so still looking for better and proper solution.

Comment: So instead, you should edit your question, add this code and note that with this code and remove this answer.  It would also help a great deal of you posted a fully functional, minimal example of working code with the "wrong" behavior (use the "snippet" button (CTRL-M) to do so.

Comment: Can't label this answer as "wrong behaviour" or making it part of question because for now this is solving my issue/question. I am just looking for any better answer that can more effectively answer my question otherwise this can be marked as an answer if didn't get more valuable answers.